# Can Hardwired Telephone Lines be used to Extend a DSL Connection?

Tags: internet-connection, dsl-modem, telephony, telecommunication

My current configuration has what appears to be an RJ11 connection going from the wall jack directly to my DSL modem.

Here is a picture of the faceplate; the blue jack is the phone line and the green jack is the "data" line.

[image: Faceplate with two RJ11 connections, one unused blue jack for analog telephone service, and one green jack with a green data cable connected to a DSL modem that is not pictured]

However, this connection is in a central hallway and I'd like to move the modem to another room without having to rewire anything.

The disused blue RJ11 connection on the same faceplate is wired to other rooms, and I don't think its connected to anything externally. I believe this blue jack is *intended* to be the "line-in" connection with the modem translating VoIP calls over the DSL connection into an analog connection for telephones in other rooms.

I am not currently using this phone line, nor do I intend to use it for connecting a landline telephone or fax in the future.

Therefore, can I simply jumper from the current green "data" jack to the disused blue "phone" jack, and then connect the modem to a phone jack in a different room?

Is there any reason why I shouldn't attempt this?

And, if this is even viable, is there anything I should test or verify beforehand to ensure I won't risk damaging anything (e.g. checking for line voltage)?

## Edit

Here is a picture showing the back of the faceplate with both jacks connected, albeit with what appears to be different wires within a shared cable:

[image: Rear of the faceplate with wires going to both jacks]

I'm not sure whether there's a DSL splitter/filter present within the NID ([Network Interface Device](https://www.homephonewiring.com/nid.html)) box - I wouldn't know what to look for. Although here is a picture showing what's inside:

[image: Interior of NID box]

Comment: I would take the face plate off, determine if anything is even connected to the blue jack, then back track it to the location where the green jack is connected to something in your utility closet.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately there's no utility closet where everything would be centrally managed. I believe the green jack is connected directly to the box on the outside of the building where the AT&T connection comes in. Whereas the blue jack is wired to single-jack faceplates in several other rooms.

Comment: You have to determine the wiring of the house.  Without that information we cannot answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound I'm unsure as to what additional information would be useful. I'm fairly certain that it's wired in the manner I described. Is there anything specific I can provide that would help to clarify things?

Comment: *"I don't think its connected to anything externally."* -- Based on pure conjecture?  Check your NID to see if you have a whole-house splitter.

Comment: “Is there anything specific I can provide that would help to clarify things?” - Take the faceplate off and determine if the jack is connected to anything.  If it’s not connected to anything then it cannot be used.  Furthermore I can’t determine what type of cable that is, looks like CAT5 or something similar definitely not RJ11

Comment: @Ramhound According to this [AT&T Forum](https://forums.att.com/t5/AT-T-Internet-Equipment/I-want-to-buy-a-longer-data-cable-for-my-u-verse/td-p/3385707) the green cable is Cat 5e with RJ11 connectors.

Comment: You should try to find an electrician and ask them to determine what exactly is going on.  That is a complete and total rats nest of wires

Comment: *"is there anything I should test or verify beforehand ..."* -- Disconnect the blue wire pair(s) from the NID.  Then the blue RJ11 jacks should not be *"connected to anything externally"* like you *"think"*.   You probably have something like     https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVewWHERYZ1dlFfjRpoJmj9pK1FHV5PzFACQ71OGAFWexKRTTC , but there may be a second voice line.  Your DSL line quality may suffer a little if you carry out your idea.